# org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Not yet implemented. while running getWindowHandles()

Tags: java, android, selenium, appium, genymotion

I am using Appium **version 1.4.16.1**, **Selenium 2.53.0** and **java-client 2.1.0**

I am getting the following error :-

> "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Not yet implemented. Please
>   help us: http://appium.io/get-involved.html (WARNING: The server did
>   not provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 7
>   milliseconds Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time:
>   '2016-03-15 16:57:40'"

when my code tried to execute

```
int windowCount = driver.getWindowHandles().size();
```

where `driver` is defined as :-

```
AndroidDriver driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

Is this a problem due to the implementation of the **code or the API**?  I am trying to detect the number of popup windows in my execution and extract the text out of the popup window.  The popup window may consist of an error message created my application or the android OS.  The device used is **Samsung Galaxy Note 3 v 4.4.4 API 19 running on Genymotion**.

Comment: probably you should update your `java-client` and then give this a try. Seems too old to confirm if the method was then implemented in `AndroidDriver`.

Comment: @nullpointer I think getWindowHandles() can only be used for browser drivers, for example FirefoxDriver().

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to use getContextHandles and no getWindowHandles.
So change your code

int windowCount = driver.getWindowHandles().size();

with this :

```
int windowCount = driver.getContextHandles().size();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is 1 solution I managed to come up with.

Instead of using

```
int windowCount = driver.getWindowHandles().size();
```

I used:

```
 List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.className("android.widget.TextView"));
```

The above gives me a list of all the elements on the popup.

I would like to thank @nullpointer for pointing me in the right direction of using uiautomatorviewer to see all the elements on the page and retrieve the values needed.

uiautomator viewer can be found in android sdk in tools folder.

```
 C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools
```

@Xenguard Thanks for sharing your experience too! :)